# Zero downtime config deployment in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

looking at the things which can be done with the [Parallel deployments in Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment), I wonder how new or changed configuration could be provided to these various versions of the application.

In a nutshell - what parallel deployment offers is that new versions of a war file can be pushed to the webapps dir (with filenames like "App##01.war, "App##02.war") and every user with a new session will get the newer version, all others stay with the old version.

So how could one provide different or additional configuration (properties) to the various versions?

Cheers.

Comment: I think this depends on how you configure your webapps. If you include some properties file on your classpath, everything will be fine. How do you configure it currently?

Comment: I use property files - but how would I update that configuration then?

Comment: I'm still not sure what kind of configuration you are referring to. Something like database connection settings? IMHO all other configuration settings should be backwards compatible.

Comment: Why does this matter? I've a new version of an application which needs new configuration - how would I be able to deploy that along with the new application version?

Let's say the old version only had one database connection configured and the new one has two blocks of db configuration - for me it seems that there's no way to get that new configuration into place without having a downtime somehow.

Comment: It really depends on how you load your configuration. For example: If you load your configuration at application startup, you could change it afterwards. So you could change it to match the new version of your application if you want to deploy it. The older version will live on with the configuration settings loaded back then when the application started up. That should be OK, because the old version will be active only for a relative short period of time (until all the sessions associated with it expired).